# Is it possible to support closed captioning with Android's native player

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, closed-captions

Does android's native player supports closed captioning while streaming a live video? If yes, is it handled automatically by the player or need to handle it separately and how?

We have a requirement specifically for android 3.0 and above to display closed captioning (preferred) or subtitles while streaming the live video.

Answer (score 8):

**Android 4.0.x version and below**

In case of Android 4.0 version and below, default Media Player did not support subtitles. 
It can be done by application themselves, More details in this [white paper](http://www.ittiam.com/IttiamAdmin/Downloads/RenderingSubtitlesinAndroid201192914525892.pdf)

**Android 4.1 (Jelly Bean - JB))**

Android JB version has built in support for internal (present in MP4 files) and SRT external subtitles. More details is available at http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.1.html#Multimedia